# ElasticSearch - Does Partial Update Create new Document if document does not exists?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to Partial Update Information in ElasticSearch Index.

If Document does not exist then Partial Update will create new Document or Discard Request??

Comment: Do you read the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_updating_a_document_that_may_not_yet_exist)?

Answer (score 1):

Update request will fail when there is no document exists in the index until unless you add an **upsert** param with key/value pairs in the update script.

Please do check the documentation before asking the question. Elastic documentation has detail about the expected behavior of the update request.